# SQL query for retrieving the combination of columns with the highest number of apparitions

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a SQL query for retrieving the combination of columns from a table which have the highest number of occurrences for identical values.
Example:

```
id  a   b   c   d   e
1   0   3   5   7   1
2   0   3   5   7   2
3   0   3   5   7   3
4   1   4   6   8   2
5   1   4   6   8   3
6   2   2   2   2   5
```

output: 0 3 5 7

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the values from the first four columns that are most common:

```
selet a, b, c, d
from t
group by a, b, c, d
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```